# Can't keep overlay out of sight once it has transitioned

Tags: css

I will eventually have a grid of embedded YouTube videos on a grid that are each initially covered by an overlay that will contain information about the relevant video. On hovering over the overlay, it slides away, leaving the video visible.

The problem is that once the overlay is out of sight, the hover is no longer in effect, so the overlay returns if you even twitch the mouse over the video. I'm bound to be missing something stupid, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Here's the CSS

```
.vid-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.vid-wrap iframe, .vid-wrap .vid-overlay {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.vid-wrap .vid-overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
.vid-wrap .vid-overlay:hover {
  top: -100%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle where you can reproduce the issue. We'll be able to help you easily that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add this CSS to fix your issue

```
.vid-wrap:hover .vid-overlay{
    top: -100%
}
```

This should fix your problem.